# OpenGL Texture Loading Predicament

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

OK, so I made a library that handles basic OpenGL rendering. It contains three buffers, one for vertices, uv's and normals. In the main render function is where I bind the buffers, enable vertex attributes, and then call glDrawArrays(). But I ran into an unexpected issue that is more engineering based then code based which is that I can only bind one texture at a time. So all the vertices will have the same textures when I draw them, How can I get around this? If you need any more source I will post it.

Main Render Function

```
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,this->_VBO);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,this->_TBO);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,this->_NBO);

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES,0,this->polyCount);

glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(2);
```

Buffers:

```
//Designated Vertex Buffer
    std::array<GLfloat,BUFFER_SIZE> BUFFER_1;
    UINT bufferIndex1;

    //Designated Normal Buffers
    std::array<GLfloat,BUFFER_SIZE> BUFFER_2;
    UINT bufferIndex2;

    //Designated UV Buffer
    std::array<GLfloat,BUFFER_SIZE> BUFFER_3;
    UINT bufferIndex3;
```

Comment: You could bind as many as `GL_MAX_TEXTURE_UNITS` textures at once. However, yes - state cannot be changed within one draw call (and that's the whole idea of what 'batch' is). Either take e.g. vertex color (or any other attribute) as texture index and take one texture out of many based on it (could be slow, depending on actual data) or split it into separate draw calls.

Answer (score 0):

What we would normally do here is split the mesh up into sub-meshes, by "material".  An object with a different texture is technically a different material, so you would render it separately.  You *can* render a single mesh using multiple textures by using something called an Atlas.  That is to say, you pack your textures into a single bitmap and choose texture coordinates within that bitmap depending on the texture you want to use.

Comment: So basically put all my textures/resources into one large file? That seems like a good idea, however the file would have to be quite large depending on all the textures I would need to put into it. Is rendering all of my vertex data at one time ok or is it more efficient to call glBufferSubData() to set the buffer for each draw call?

Comment: It depends as there are lots of variables when it comes to performance.  For example, if you're rendering several thousand entities, each with a different texture, those calls into the driver on every frame start adding up. So you might try to think of an optimisation strategy for that.  If you have lots of different shaders, you might sort your drawable entities by shader to minimise state changes, etc.  Try different things and profile.